# Cant extend html template on Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

I cant extends one html document (child - base_home.html) to another parent html document - base.html
I have next Django project structure:

```
Testdjango/
blog/
   migrations/
   templates/
       blog/
          base.html
          base_home.html
   __init.py__
   admin.py
   apps.py
   models.py
   tests.py
   urls.py
   views.py
db.sqlite3
manage.py
```

My parent template is a base.html, with the next code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} &ndash; Blog</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/journal/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template
    <link href="starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

    </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Blog</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}

    </div>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     </body>
</html>
```

And my "child" base_home.html have next code:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block title %}
Home
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
Lorem bla bla
{% endblock %}
```

And in page i cant see anything from base_home.html

Comment: If you render `base_home.html`, do you see the html content rendered on the web pgae?

Comment: Please show your view.

Comment: my view:
 `from django.http import HttpResponse, request
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create youcoding=utf-8r views here.


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/base.html')`

Comment: @karthikr, no, cant see anything from base_home.html

Comment: Can you paste the stack trace of the extends error. It will be easy to debug that time. My guess is that, you have not given the template_dirs path properly in settings.py.

Comment: The code looks good. So, did you add the `blog` folder to your TEMPLATES DIRS locations?

Comment: @Ixer Right, now i change my view, and now working. Tell me please. In view.py i need render to "base.html" where i have main html code. or to file where i have {extend}?

Answer (score 4):

Your templates seems okay, make sure your Template settings looks something like this, also you have added the app to **`INSTALLED_APPS`**.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

and since `base.html` and `base_home.html` are in same dir, extend base as,

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

Comment: Django use templates folder. So i need write "blog/base.html" because directory "blog" in directory "templates"

Answer (score 0):

try

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

instead of

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extends the templates in two ways

1. `include` ## Include a perticular section of html into template
2. `extends` ## Extends common html into diff pages

base.html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
======
======
</body>
</html>

home.html

If base.html in any folder please mention folder name dont put slash(/) before the foldername `{% extends 'foldername/base.html' %}` 

{% extends 'base.html' %} ## you can see the base.html styles in the home.html
```

suppose you need to include a perticular div,tables or section of code use 
`{% include 'base.html' %}` if its in folder `{% include 'foldername/base.html' %}`

Comment: i delete "extend" from base_home and put {% include "blog/base_home.html" %}.
NOW I SEE {% block content %} but cant see {% block title %} (home)

Comment: `include` is only for include a perticular section in the html , please use `extends`

Comment: so you say me, that my code is good? But i tried use just `{% extends "base.html %}` or `{% extends "blog/base.html" %}` in base_home.html, and its not worked for me. Maybe something wrong in settings?

Answer (score 0):

do you have something similar to

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'DIRS': [
            str(ROOT_DIR.path('templates')),
        ],`...
```

in your settings?

and do you have your blog app registered in project settings `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Answer (score 0):

I think i find the asnwer. In my view i have return render(request, "blog/base.html").  I chage it to return render(request, "blog/base_home.html") - where i have extend. And now its working. Tell me please, it true?

Answer (score -1):

Django doesn't recognize which block you are trying to end. You need to define this.

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block title %}
Home
{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
Lorem bla bla
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: No. You don't *necessarily* have to mention block name in `endblock`. It is optional. Check [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance).

Comment: @dennis-slimmers its not working too, unfortunatelly